# Creating a serial number

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a serial number for my program.

I'd like it to represent the relevant dates as well as the user's name, company's name, etc.
Is there a common way to do this?

A link to a tutorial/ article  will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can't you just create a string which concatenates the various bits of info?

Comment: yes, but I was wondering if there's a standard way...

Comment: What would be the purpose of such serial number? Does it have to be reversible? If not, just concatenate all the info, add some secret salt and use a hash like e.g. SHA1. To display the result choose your favorite base (hex and base64 representations are simple and widely used).

Comment: It's supposed to protect the program so nobody will be able to use it when the license expires. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look to the definition of the [UUID (Universal Unique ID)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) which allows you to generate a unique number based on different parameters (MAC, date...)

Comment: But how can I make sure that the serial number will contain only numbers and digits?

Comment: @Idov : UUID can be represented by an hexadecimal string

Answer (score 1):

Consider hash-functions (with salt) based on text that user provides.

Answer (score 0):

It is usually done with hash of some sort. For a start you can read [this article](http://www.seoxys.com/registration-schemes-serial-numers/) with simple enough registration scheme and corresponding discussion.